# Automating generation of Project documents

Tags: azure-devops

We have lots of project documents for each release and we want that to be automated.Lots of word documents are there with tables which are populated through scripts.Right now we run script manually and then fill the word doc.Is there any way to automate it using azure devops and once word is created with data then to convert it to pdf format

Answer (score 0):

I use the powershell script to convert word doc to pdf as following:
[image]

I run this pipeline in my default agent pool and specified the file path. And finally, the word doc was successfully convert to pdf.
[image]

So I recommand you to add a powershell task after generating the Word doc ,and run the specified powershell script(if you also use the powershell script to convert Word doc). so you can automatically convert Word doc to PDF format each time you generate a Word doc. By specifying the file path, you can automatically convert the Word doc to PDF format.

Comment: Thanks this is useful.Can you guide me the steps to how to automate generation of word document to populate data inside tables of doc using powershell script without manual work?